# Redirecting outside a web app?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

This is my first time developing a rails app from scratch. The goal of my code is to use a title and link (both stored in a database table) to redirect users to the link. (Problem) When I click the link title, I'm redirected to localhost:3000/google.com instead of google.com. (Assuming google.com was the value in link.link)

```
<h1>Links#index</h1>

<% @links.each do |link| %>
<p>
<%= link_to link.title, link.link %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Notes:

(1) Using Rails 3.1

(2) The contents of my routes.rb file are below (Not sure if the use of `resources :links` has something to do with my problem)

```
CodeHed::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :links
  get "links/index"
  root :to => "links#index"
end
```

Comment: Solved. You must include HTTP:// with the url value in the table for Rails to redirect users outside of the app. Otherwise, the value will be appended to the current url. As was the case with localhost:3000/google.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your links prefixed with "http://"? If not, try adding that in programmatically with something like:

```
def add_http(link)
  if (link =~ /http(?:s)?:\/\//)
    link
  else
    "http://#{link}"
  end
end
```

If that doesn't work then you could simply enter raw html:

```
<h1>Links#index</h1>

<% @links.each do |link| %>
<p>
  <%= link_to title, add_http(link) %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

(I haven't checked this code)

Comment: Just commented my own question before I realized you answered it. That was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Before I realized that was the problem, I tried the "a href" method. FYI, without the http:// it just appends the url to the current one.